# Too much recursion from one out of two links calling the same function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

To start with I read alot of threads with this problem and solved it myself before. But this matter leaves me confused..

**Code**

```
<Leads:LeadsListing runat="server" ID="MyLeadsList" List="MyLeads"/>
<Leads:LeadsListing runat="server" ID="NewLeadsList" List="Unassigned" />
```

Both fetches the same gridview, but have filters being applied to them (which work perfectly fine)

This script being called on `Page_Load`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    Detailsupdatepanel,
        Detailsupdatepanel.GetType()
            "clickableTrs",

    "$('#" + LeadsGridview.ClientID + "table tr td:first-child a').each(function(){
        var func = Function('event', this.href.substring(\"javascript:\".length) +';
        if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();
        } else{
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }');
        this.href = '#';
        $(this).click(func);
    });

    $('.DarkBackground, .ahover').click(function(){
        $('#" + LeadsGridview.ClientID + " tr td:first-child a').unbind('click');
        $(this).find('a').click();
    });",

true);
```

I do not understand how only the first gridview **(on  click)** gives me error saying "too much recursion", while it works fine on the second gridview. Specially when both call the exact same function and look exactly the same? Apart from being filtered :(

**Edit**

This is what the html rendering looks like,

```
<asp:GridView ID="LeadsGridview" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" CssClass="Basic" Width="98%" gridlines="None" allowsorting="True" autogeneratecolumns="False" EnableViewState="true">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeaderStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="DarkBackground" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="ahover" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="ShowDetailsClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'><%# Eval("Company") %></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("CreatedDate") as string).ToString("d") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="D1_contact__r" HeaderText="Contact" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="D2_owner__r" HeaderText="Owner" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="D2_contact__r" HeaderText="Owner" />
    </Columns>                    
</asp:GridView>
```

To make the whole  clickable instead of just the link in the first  I'm unbinding that click event and then rebinding it to the . I had some issues here before since its an ajax call (the href = `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainArea$MainArea$Cart$ContentItem$ctl00$EditCartButton','')`)

Comment: What was the purpose of the `unbind` before raising the `click` event? Can you add the actual rendered HTML for these two links?

Comment: Provide rendered HTML, not unreadeable server side code

Comment: Why are you defining the same function over and over again in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, updated with additional information!

Comment: @Groo Explained why I unbind and bind the click to something else! Hope this can bring some light over the rest